# Create object android not final

Tags: java, android, xml, class

I have a problem:
well, I have this class:

```
class objectoA{
   int a;
   int b;

   objetoA(int tam, int longitud)
      {
         this.a=tam;
         this.b=longitud;
      }
}
```

Also , I have a Activity that have a Spinner, SeekBar, and button.
I want to click to button and this botton catch the values of spinner and seekbar and put this into the objetoA constructor but I dont know do that because if I put the code into setOnClickListener eclipse show a error and If I put the code out the setOnClickListener , the object put default values.

So, I have declarate:

```
objectoA ABC;
```

Spinner code:

```
spinnerw.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        tamw=Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());               
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
```

This is the button code:

```
        gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
--------------->ABC=new objectoA(tamw);
            }
        });
```

So, when I have the spinner value save into tamw, I want to create the object when I push the button.
what have I do?
Thanks you!!

Comment: You need to post more relevant code.

Comment: Definitely can't call your `int` "long." `long` is a primitive data type.

Comment: lol! it's not long xD.  Ok I'm going to edit the post.

Comment: you could just use getters and setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't accessed a local variable into a inner class like this.
To access your `ABC` variable in the `OnClickListener` you have two solutions:

- Make it `final`. But then you can not instantiate it.
- Make it a property of your `Activity` :

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      private objectoA ABC;
      /* your code */
  }
  ```